# Automatically regenerate Text Templates that depends upon multiple files

Tags: visual-studio, code-generation, project, t4

My situation:

- I have a VS 2010 project with 3 files:

  - content.txt
  - generator.tt
  - generated.js  (generated via T4)
- The project file contains them as:

  ```
  <None Include="generator.tt">
    <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
    <LastGenOutput>generated.js</LastGenOutput>
  </None>
  <Content Include="content.txt" />
  <Content Include="generated.js">
    <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
    <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    <DependentUpon>generator.tt</DependentUpon>
  </Content>
  ```
- The generated.js will be regenerated on every change of generator.tt

is there a way to automatically regenerating generated.js on changes to one of the other files (without using any plugin)?
I've tried to simply add another DependentUpon Element. But VS only takes care of the last one...

Thanks for your ideas

Edit:

I've forgotten one detail:
- The solution has to work with TFS. So it has to do a "Check Out for Edit..." when files are modified.

Comment: I would use TextTransform.exe (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126245) and postbuild actions. Potentially Writing a small wrapper exe that checks for dates the files the template is dependent upon. MSBuild is possibility too but I have very Little experience with that.

Comment: We have a postbuild solution running right now. But the point is that when developing JavaScript you do not need to rebuild the solution on every change. So many developer simply forget to build or regenerate the files.

Comment: Hi, we have evaluated The VS Extension "T4 Regenerator" which fit most of our requirements. It regenerates all T4 Templates in a folder when a file in this folder was changed. In conjunction with "tfpt uu /noget" it's ok. But it is still not a good solution.